# $location.search().name and base href breaks application URL - Need Guidance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a angular app and my URL seems http://localhost:8080/personal?name=xyz and i'm using $location.search().name to get xyz in js.

My code as follows..

app.js

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true});
});

app.controller('myController', function($location) {
var name = $location.search().name;
alert(name); // xyz
```

index.html

```
<base href="/" />
```

the functionality is working well but it breaks my URL to localhost:8080, how to set my base href to get localhost:8080/personal

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: i have tried <base href="/home" /> and <base href="/home/" /> but nothing seems working. How to get URL like localhost:8080/home

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as desired by changing my $location.path from my controllers and templateUrl's on routeProvider